# how to check the field "select"?

Tags: python, django

please help check field 'select'.

model:

```
class Message(models.Model):        
    reciever = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='recipient',
        blank=False,
        null=False, 
    )   
    theme = models.CharField(
        'Тема сообщения',
        max_length=200, 
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )       
    text = models.TextField(
        'Текст сообщения',
        max_length=10000, 
        blank=False,
    )
```

forms:

```
class CreateMessageForm(forms.ModelForm):               
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = (
            'reciever', 
            'theme', 
            'text', 
        )

    def clean_reciever(self):
        reciever = self.cleaned_data['reciever']
        if reciever == '':
            raise forms.ValidationError("Это обязательное поле")            

        return reciever
```

tpl:

```
<form id="createMessageForm"action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="cell input_outer">
        <label class="label">{{ form.reciever.label }}</label>

        {{ form.reciever }}

        {{ form.reciever.errors }}
    </div>          

    <div class="cell input_outer">
        <label class="label">{{ form.theme.label }}</label>

        {{ form.theme }}

        {{ form.theme.errors }}
    </div>  

    <div class="cell textarea_outer textarea_message">
        <label class="label">{{ form.text.label }}</label>

        {{ form.text }}

        {{ form.text.errors }}
    </div>          

    <div class="cell submit_outer">
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Отправить" />
    </div>
</form>
```

field reciever this drop-down list. I need to check the value of the field reciever. need to not filled field reciever display the error message.

my code does not work. that is, an error message is displayed.

Comment: it is always helpful to see the error message if there is one. Can you attach it?

Comment: add in question template.html

Comment: Ah, so a _validation error_ is displayed on submit?

Comment: no. validation errors not displayed on submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

> The clean_() method in a form subclass – where  is replaced with the name of the form field attribute. This method does any cleaning that is specific to that particular attribute, unrelated to the type of field that it is. This method is not passed any parameters. You will need to look up the value of the field in self.cleaned_data and remember that it will be a Python object at this point, not the original string submitted in the form (it will be in cleaned_data because the general field clean() method, above, has already cleaned the data once).

So the value that has been input by the user in the receiver (mind the spelling) field is not what is contained in self.cleaned_data["receiver"]. You have to modify your check in the line

```
if receiver == '':
```